# VC dimension of 1-NN classifier for discrete metric space?

Tags: vc-dimension

We know VC dimension of 1-NN classifier is infinite for continuous metric space. Is there any proof of VC dimension of 1-NN classifier if the metric space is discrete?

Comment: What do you think?